# What contention is in case of critical sections

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, critical-section

I recently read that the critical sections in Windows doesn't go into the kernel unless they have a contention. Unfortunately, I didn't understand quite correctly what does it actually mean. What this "contention" is?

Comment: If thread A already has the critical section locked, and thread B tries to lock it as well, you have a contention and thread B has to wait.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter So, critical sections are only fast when they are not already locked by another thread?

Comment: If they're blocked by another thread it's not a question of them being "not fast"; they have to wait until the other thread unlocks the CS. Which takes as long as it takes.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter I mean that critical sections go to the kernel only if this critical section was already locked, otherwise it just increments the "lock counter". Am I right?

Comment: I believe that's how it works, yes.